# PhoneGap Android Querystring issue

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, query-string

I seem to be having a issue using phoneGap with querystrings

I wanted to have a page as:

view.html?matchid=1234

I have also tried:

view.html#1234

Both of these work in the emulator (running 2.3) but neither work when on my phone (ICS 4.0) - It errors as if the page doesn't exists...

I believe it may be a issue with the version of android. Does anyone know of a fix/work around I could possibly do.

Ideally it would be still using the query in some way. If not the other option I thought of was to use localStorage. Save something to it before going to a generic view.html page which then takes the Id out of localStorage....

Comment: Are you passing this into loadUrl? Or how are you accessing it?

Comment: Simple bit of javascript to change pages based on a table row click document.location.href = "view.html#" + MatchId;

Comment: And how are you loading the URL for phonegap?

Comment: the firs page loads up correctly:
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

but after clicking on a row of a table I hit some JS which does:
document.location.href = "view.html#" + MatchId;

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue for this in the Android issue tracker.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

It affects all versions of Honeycomb and ICS.

It has been fixed and marked for Future release, so don't expect it anytime soon.

You can find some workarounds on the issue thread.