# phonegap URL with get variables not loading?

Tags: http, cordova, get

We've put together an app that is mostly working in phonegap. We have an "Advanced Search" page with a few fields, something like this:

```
LAST:     ______
FIRST:    Rob___
BUSINESS: ______
WORK ID:  ______
RESULTS PER PAGE
---[20]---------

    [SEARCH]
```

When you click the search button, it'll take you to the "Search Results" page and pass all the parameters to it through a GET, so the url when you load the page would look like this `http://some.domain.com/SearchResults.html?lname=&fname=Rob&business=&workid=&slider=20` in a browser, and in phonegap it points to a file in the `www` folder, SearchResults.html, but it's looking for the file `SearchResults.html?lname=&fname=Rob&business=&workid=&slider=20` which is obviously not going to be there. What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9902089/807032

Was just an issue with honeycomb and ICS on android.